# ComboBox SelectedItem binding does not work for an object in a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="main_grid">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Things, ElementName=main_grid}" SelectedItem="{Binding .}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

`MyThings` and `Things` are both `ObservableCollection<Thing>`.

If `Things` contains three objects, and I have added one of them to `MyThings`, when the view/XAML loads the `ComboBox` will initially display that item. However, when I change the selection in the `ComboBox`, the item within `MyThings` is not replace with the newly selected item as I would expect (if it were bound to a single object, rather than an object in a collection, it would be replaced).

Why does this not work? And is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Your expectation is wrong. `SelectedItem="{Binding .}"` won't do anything, especially not replace an item in a collection.

Comment: SelectedItem bindings are primarily bound back to the view model to know what item the user has selected.  So you could add a variable `SelectedThing` to the view model (the main_grid.DataContext) and then update the binding from `{Binding .}` to `{Binding SelectedThing}`.  Now note if you set the binding two way and then from code set SelectedThing to a `Thing` NOT within the `ItemsSource` it will not add it to the collection.  I don't really know of any binding that would act like that.

Comment: A SelectedThing property in the view model could of course replace an item in the MyThings collection with its value. It must however somehow be told which one. To me it is entirely unclear what this UI is supposed to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - it's making sense in my head now - in the single item example the binding is to a reference in the ViewModel, and not to "itself". @Clemens, what I'm trying to implement is a list of items on the ViewModel, and then a UI where the user can add some of those items to another collection, by selecting it from a ComboBox (the user could then change it to a different item, etc.).

Comment: @ChrisMack I would personally add a wrapper class around the selected item which would have a property for the actual selected item.  So that when the user selects a different item from the combo box only the property is updated and not the actual item within the collection.  However Clemens' comment seems to refer to someway to actually update the item within the collection (I didn't think that was possible so I won't be much help with that approach)

Comment: @chancea Thanks, the wrapper class is actually the approach I’ve gone for :) Your point about switching an item and it not being added to the collection really helped me understand where I was going wrong, so thanks for that!